# Counting the frequency of hex characters in a .txt file

Tags: c++, hex

I have a file that contains hexadecimal values separated by spaces. I want to find the frequency of each of the hex values and write it to a text file. For example, consider the string `"1b 17 3c 45 3f 52 7a 5a 3b 45 31 52 2e 17 3e 58 3f 44 "`. I want to count the frequency of occurrence of each hex value:

```
1b - 1 times 
17 - 2 times
.... so on.
```

I have currently written a c++ program but it counts the space between the hex characters as a hex character as well and does not function as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int x  = 0;
    int total[128] = {0};
    int index;

    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    infile.open("hex.txt");
    outfile.open("results2.txt");
    if(!infile)
    {
        cout << "Error opening input file" << endl;
        return 0;
    }   

    char c;
    while(infile.get(c))
    {
        index = c;
        total[index]++;
    } 

    for (int i=0; i<128; i++)      // Print the results
    {
        outfile << "  " << hex << i << " occurs "
                << setw(5) << dec << total[i] << " times" 
                << "  " << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note:

```
"hex.txt" is the input file
"results2.txt" is the output file
```

Comment: Read [ask] and follow the advice. And don't spam tags. C and C++ are **disctinct** languages!

Comment: And what is your question? How far have you come on your own?

Comment: Use [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: Use [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: If using a map, you would read the values as strings, not individual characters.  The stream input operator will skip over whitespace.  Alternatively set the input stream manipulator to hex and read the values converted to integers which will work with your `total` array.  But you should beware of out-of-bounds access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply read the input file as hex:

```
while(infile >> hex >> index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= 128) {   // ensure value is in array range...
        cerr << "Found an incorrect value " << hex << index << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    total[index]++;
}
```